# php and mysql results mark keywords

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to search with php and mysql.
I want to mark keyword after search result get.

I can do it case insensitive like this.

```
echo str_ireplace($keyword,'<mark>'.$keyword.'</mark>',$data["text"]);
```

I have problem some characters.

For example

if my keyword is şef and my text has Şef i cant replace

some other example

keyword ağaç   text AĞAÇ 
keyword ŞİRİN   text şirin

I want to replace every think  but i didn't. How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input is utf-8, try [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with case insensitive [unicode regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) by setting the `i` and `u` [flags](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

```
$search = '/'.preg_quote($keyword, "/").'/iu';

echo preg_replace($search, '<mark>\0</mark>', $data["text"]);
```

Might want to add `\b` [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before and after the searchword.

---

*Update according comments*

To also match such as `sirin` with searchword `ŞİRİN` possibly need to build a regex pattern:

```
$kw_map = array(
'/[cç]/iu' => "[cç]",
'/[iİ]/iu' => "[iİ]",
'/[gğ]/iu' => "[gğ]",
'/[sş]/iu' => "[sş]",
# ...add more here
);
```

build the pattern:

```
$keyword = "ŞİRİN";

$search = '/'.preg_replace(array_keys($kw_map), array_values($kw_map), $keyword).'/iu';
```

If you `echo $search` it looks like `/[sş][iİ]R[iİ]N/iu`; Now replace:

```
echo preg_replace($search, '<mark>\0</mark>', $data["text"]);
```

See [example on eval.in](https://eval.in/239195)

Comment: thank you for response. I learned u flag from your answer. I have a question too. if it is pobsible mark if keyword Şirin and text has sirin i want to mark sirin how can do it. or like this keyword ağaç or keyword agaç  i want to mark in text agac or opposite

Comment: @sfk for that you possibly need to specify such as `a[gğ]a[cç]` (need to build a regex pattern from the keyword, because that are different characters)

Comment: I am not well regex. Can you give me an example pattern please. Thank you so much.

Comment: @sfk Added an example. You need to add your characters to `$kw_map`.